# Не могу пройти простейшую задачку в javarush. проверьте мою логику

Tags: java

Задание и требования:
Закомментируй те переменные, которые нигде не используются. Программа должна компилироваться.

Тип переменных менять нельзя.

•   Значения переменных менять нельзя.

•   В программу нельзя добавлять новые строки или удалять имеющиеся.

•   Нужно закомментировать неиспользуемые переменные.

•   Вывод программы не должен измениться.

```
package com.javarush.task.task01.task0123;

/* 
Лишние строки нам не нужны
*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 15;
        double c = b + 38;
        //int d = a + 12;
        //double e = 12.3;
        String s = s + "a";
        String s1 = a + "b";
        //String s2 = "a";
        String s3 = s1 + a;
        String s4 = s3 + b;
        System.out.println(c + s4 + s);
    }
}
```

Для начала просчитываем что выведется на экран, в System.out.println(c + s4 + s):

Узнаем 3 неизвестных:

Узнаем с (первая неизвестная)

с = (15+38) = 53.0 (тип - число)

Узнаем s4 (вторая неизвестная)

s4 = (s3+15)

Узнаем s3

s3 = (s1+10)

Узнаем s1

s1 = (10 +"b")=10b (тип - строка)

Отсюда s3 = (10b+10)=10b10 (тип строка)

Отсюда s4 = (10b10+15)=10b1015 (тип строка)

Узнаем s (3 неизвестную):

s=(s+"a") = a (тип текст)

Складывая все неизвестные получаем:

System.out.println(53.0 + 10b1015 + a): = 53.010b1015a - то, что должно вывести на экран.

В расчетах мы не использовали переменные d,e,s2 и соответственно комментируем их как лишние и завершаем задание, но нет ошибка..."Возможно переменная "s" не проинициализирована."

Почему это она не проинициализирована? ей задали (пустое значение + a)- получилось значение "a"...ниче не понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ошибка..."Возможно переменная "s" не проинициализирована."

Правильно.

Потому что код с ошибкой.

Потому что первое использование `s` - в выражении

```
String s = s + "a";
```

по правую руку от знака равенства, а в этот момент она не определена, выше кода её определения нет.

Т.е. нужно закомментировать эту строку, и ещё строку, где она используется, т.е.

```
System.out.println(c + s4 + s);
```

Так не будет "лишних" переменных, и будет компилироваться без ошибок.

Если начнутся вопли, что программа теперь ничего не выводит - останется только сказать, что в такой постановке задача не решается, условие противоречиво.

---

Ещё есть вариант - закомментировать не всю последнюю строку, а только фрагмент `+ s` в ней.

---

> Складывая все неизвестные получаем:
>
> System.out.println(53.0 + 10b1015 + a): = 53.010b1015a - то, что
>   должно вывести на экран.

В задании в этом месте `s`, а не `a`.

Если это опечатка в ЗАДАНИИ, и должно быть именно `a`, то достаточно закомментировать `String s = s + "a";`.

Comment: Ответ был следующим- нужно было закомментировать строчки с переменными d,e,s2 и обернуть s в кавычки в строке с переменной s        (String s = "s" + a;) но это получается, что мы изменяем значение переменной, а это запрещено правилами задачи, короче бомбит меня))

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко И всё же как должно быть: `System.out.println(c + s4 + s);`, как в тексте задания, или `System.out.println(c + s4 + a);`? как в тексте твоего рассуждения?

Comment: System.out.println(c + s4 + s); должно быть - вывод (53.010b1015s10)